# Altair visualization with mark image breaks using certain images

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, dashboard, altair

I've been practicing my usage of Altair and recently decided to create a dashboard to analyze Magic The Gathering decks, using Scryfall to obtain card information. One of the visualizations in my dashboard is a table filled with rows and columns, each containing an image of a card from the deck, with a tooltip for zooming in on the card. However, I've encountered a problem where the visualization breaks for some decks, either not showing certain cards or causing visual glitches that spill into other sections of the dashboard. After isolating and modifying parts of my code, I discovered that the issue seems to be related to some of the card images themselves. Strangely, all the images are obtained in the same manner from the same source, and as far as my verification goes, they appear to have the same properties (width and height) and format (PNG). Regardless, certain images seem to crash the visualization while others do not, and I can't identify any clear pattern as to why this happens. Could anyone provide some ideas or insights on what might be happening? Below, I'll share an example of the visualization code, the pandas table from which it takes the information and an image of how the visualization looks when broken (outside of the dashboard).

Example of Pandas Dataframe the Chart is Made from
[image: Example of Pandas Dataframe the Chart is Made from]

Example of Code for Visualization
[image: Example of Code for Visualization]

Example of Broken Visualization Outside Dashboard
[image: Example of Broken Visualization Outside Dashboard]

Example of Broken Visualization In Dashboard
[image: Example of Broken Visualization In Dashboard]

The visualization should look like the visualizations bellow (this is an example where Ive removed all the images I found where problematic through trial and error in a deck)

Working Visualization Outside Dashboard
[image: Working Visualization Outside Dashboard]

Working Visualization In Dashboard
[image: Working Visualization In Dashboard]

---

### Reproducible Code

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd


dis = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")


alt.Chart(dis.rename(columns={"Card_Image":"image"}),title= "Card Names").mark_image().encode(

    # Using Row designator as X axis
    x= alt.X("Column:N",sort="x",axis=None),

    # Using Row designator as Y axis
    y= alt.Y("Row:N",axis=None),

    url = "image",

    # Applying tooltip for image of Card
    tooltip=["image"]

    # Adding type and color selection filters
).properties(height=700,width=700)
```

---

### Usable Data in CSV Format

```
,Card_Image,Column,Row
0,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/2/d/2daa3621-8a2c-4b4b-87ac-f981192a0567.jpg?1675957256,1,1
1,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/a/1/a16fabbe-4557-4067-b882-f2e5dbd8b458.jpg?1626099357,2,1
2,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/e/a/eaedf482-9f2c-497a-bf1c-bebb4168c52f.jpg?1631585769,3,1
3,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/b/3/b378c8bf-85ed-4d28-aec9-4925d12bca4a.jpg?1599710077,4,1
4,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/6/1670393d-86f0-46fb-b577-f73a1da2a3ed.jpg?1682205808,5,1
5,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/c/0/c081e5cf-81e2-4afb-a912-8267de29e88d.jpg?1562202493,1,2
6,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/2/b/2be8d24e-1370-4e85-90f2-66b6d6e9c4a4.jpg?1562202498,2,2
7,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/6/f/6f380a12-9656-479e-bd44-1b8facfcc69c.jpg?1651656424,3,2
8,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/4/6/46e6f50b-4b18-4aab-a7b0-869f25bc4c40.jpg?1599710135,4,2
9,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/3/b/3bfa6b8c-6e4b-42fa-9f6c-40c95e162b9a.jpg?1631589231,5,2
10,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/a/b/abbc5ae5-8e8b-4106-844f-2d49d2a51ed9.jpg?1562821604,1,3
11,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/b/e/be294c4e-712b-459c-a36c-e26ed5c27edb.jpg?1624740762,2,3
12,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/0/10e9cbf2-99ed-4f70-8744-b9a08a5f5f42.jpg?1674142776,3,3
13,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/7/17bfb8c5-9105-41e4-a58f-9c9eee32b18a.jpg?1674422106,4,3
14,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/7/17bfb8c5-9105-41e4-a58f-9c9eee32b18a.jpg?1674422106,5,3
15,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/3/6/36ee958c-ae8c-49bd-9d85-0128ca19901c.jpg?1686972021,1,4
16,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/a/f/afeb5a30-016a-465f-bdf0-e2df2d1bef8c.jpg?1592757830,2,4
17,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/6/b/6b1bab36-3fb7-48f3-b3ed-90863d244641.jpg?1562849914,3,4
18,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/8/6/86c9838e-aa72-49fc-bae2-f880bcbc9313.jpg?1562614038,4,4
19,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/0/10e35711-aec9-4024-a2a6-9efff8c71df2.jpg?1562826882,5,4
20,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/2/1/2154e3c6-ab69-4661-b1ef-a50cc0f6f763.jpg?1562610098,1,5
21,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/0/3/033aa2cd-531c-4594-a7eb-b3cbeb2c5a3c.jpg?1581708589,2,5
22,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/5/e/5ead169f-4777-405b-9a5e-60a7aefa70a7.jpg?1562912463,3,5
23,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/6/d/6d989daa-78eb-4120-81b5-7866a7b04590.jpg?1562819570,4,5
24,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/0/5/05812009-d1b8-4775-8188-f05cfdb4feed.jpg?1592711384,5,5
```

In this Code, eliminating the first image or substituting it with another one of the dataset's images, fixes the visualization.

Comment: HI Galen! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Your question will get answered 10x faster if you include code and/or data with your question (enough that people can reproduce your problem). Screenshots while great, are a poor substitute for the real thing

Comment: Thank you @Mark. I have added some data, as well as some code that can be used to reproduce the effects. For whatever reason, I cant get the imports in the code to be in separate lines within StackOverflow. However, aside from fixing that, one should be able to recreate the visualization witht he data provided. In this case, if you remove the first row of data, or replace the image url with another, the problem is fixed. I do not know why.

Comment: I don't know if the examples you included are only good ones, but the code worked for me?

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an idea of what I ran- this gives me a HTML file which gives a grid with no missing values on my computer:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


dis = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
,Card_Image,Column,Row
0,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/2/d/2daa3621-8a2c-4b4b-87ac-f981192a0567.jpg?1675957256,1,1
1,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/a/1/a16fabbe-4557-4067-b882-f2e5dbd8b458.jpg?1626099357,2,1
2,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/e/a/eaedf482-9f2c-497a-bf1c-bebb4168c52f.jpg?1631585769,3,1
3,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/b/3/b378c8bf-85ed-4d28-aec9-4925d12bca4a.jpg?1599710077,4,1
4,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/6/1670393d-86f0-46fb-b577-f73a1da2a3ed.jpg?1682205808,5,1
5,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/c/0/c081e5cf-81e2-4afb-a912-8267de29e88d.jpg?1562202493,1,2
6,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/2/b/2be8d24e-1370-4e85-90f2-66b6d6e9c4a4.jpg?1562202498,2,2
7,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/6/f/6f380a12-9656-479e-bd44-1b8facfcc69c.jpg?1651656424,3,2
8,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/4/6/46e6f50b-4b18-4aab-a7b0-869f25bc4c40.jpg?1599710135,4,2
9,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/3/b/3bfa6b8c-6e4b-42fa-9f6c-40c95e162b9a.jpg?1631589231,5,2
10,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/a/b/abbc5ae5-8e8b-4106-844f-2d49d2a51ed9.jpg?1562821604,1,3
11,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/b/e/be294c4e-712b-459c-a36c-e26ed5c27edb.jpg?1624740762,2,3
12,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/0/10e9cbf2-99ed-4f70-8744-b9a08a5f5f42.jpg?1674142776,3,3
13,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/7/17bfb8c5-9105-41e4-a58f-9c9eee32b18a.jpg?1674422106,4,3
14,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/7/17bfb8c5-9105-41e4-a58f-9c9eee32b18a.jpg?1674422106,5,3
15,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/3/6/36ee958c-ae8c-49bd-9d85-0128ca19901c.jpg?1686972021,1,4
16,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/a/f/afeb5a30-016a-465f-bdf0-e2df2d1bef8c.jpg?1592757830,2,4
17,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/6/b/6b1bab36-3fb7-48f3-b3ed-90863d244641.jpg?1562849914,3,4
18,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/8/6/86c9838e-aa72-49fc-bae2-f880bcbc9313.jpg?1562614038,4,4
19,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/1/0/10e35711-aec9-4024-a2a6-9efff8c71df2.jpg?1562826882,5,4
20,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/2/1/2154e3c6-ab69-4661-b1ef-a50cc0f6f763.jpg?1562610098,1,5
21,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/0/3/033aa2cd-531c-4594-a7eb-b3cbeb2c5a3c.jpg?1581708589,2,5
22,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/5/e/5ead169f-4777-405b-9a5e-60a7aefa70a7.jpg?1562912463,3,5
23,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/6/d/6d989daa-78eb-4120-81b5-7866a7b04590.jpg?1562819570,4,5
24,https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/0/5/05812009-d1b8-4775-8188-f05cfdb4feed.jpg?1592711384,5,5
"""))

a = alt.Chart(dis.rename(columns={"Card_Image":"image"}),title= "Card Names").mark_image().encode(

    # Using Row designator as X axis
    x= alt.X("Column:N",sort="x",axis=None),

    # Using Row designator as Y axis
    y= alt.Y("Row:N",axis=None),

    url = "image",

    # Applying tooltip for image of Card
    tooltip=["image"]

    # Adding type and color selection filters
).properties(height=700,width=700)

a.save("a.html")
```

[image: the website]

Comment: Hello @Mark, thanks for the continued help. The first url should be the one causing the problem. Using your code, I still get the error. Not sure what could be causing the problem for me but not for you. When eliminating the first URL, I get a fixed display (seen bellow). When running your code I do get the follwoing error (not certain its related):
FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead. for col_name, dtype in df.dtypes.iteritems():  
Broken
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtZNg.png 
Not Broken
https://i.stack.imgur.com/71ZRC.png

Comment: @Galen I just tried this on a second computer (first one Mac, second one Windows). Both work. What happens if you run all of the code within a fresh Python process, and then open the "a.html" file in your browser?

Comment: your code doesn't save the Altair visualisation, and for whatever reason it doesn't pop up in VS Code for me. I'm wondering if maybe this is opening in your IDE somehow but the html version may work (but idk)

Comment: Hey mark, I updated my altair and pandas versions and also deleted my browser caches to see if that fixed the issue. It seemd to do so. So the problem is currently fixed for the visualization. However, in updating my altair version, the whole dashboard no longer seems to function together. The new error reads: Javascript Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback. However, I'll see about fixing that tomorrow. Thank you for the help on the first issue.

Comment: Hello @Mark, yes. The visualization seems to work properly now. I believe it was both a combination of the not up to date altair library and the browser cache. The dashboard no longer seems to crash and the very rare times it has, after deleting my cache, it functions normally again.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Altair and Pandas, as well as deleting my browser's cache, seems to have fixed the error for the individual visualization. Though now, because of the updates, the dashboard doesnt function as it previously did and will need to be changed.